# The first API call takes more time to respond than further API calls

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am making API calls from my android application using Retrofit2. The first API call which is made just after creating Retrofit client takes around 1000ms to 1200ms to respond. But further API calls, where initially created client is reused, takes 300ms to 350ms(These readings are with full speed internet).

I have done querying the backend with Postman. The above readings match to the reading I get there as well. Means even Postman takes more time to respond initially.

Any idea on why is this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please add some code? Also, I guess this also (or mainly) depends on your backend. Did you try querying your backend with an external software? Like, for example, Postman. If it depends on your backend, then you should experience the same behaviour from Postman too.

Comment: Yes, I have done querying the backend with Postman. The above readings match to the reading I get there as well. Means even Postman takes more time to respond initially.

Comment: It seems pretty normal behaviour, to me. The first time you call it, the API is loaded in memory (which takes some time), then executed. The next time(s) you use it, it's already loaded, therefore it's faster.

Comment: Ok, then I guess there is some HTTP cache mechanism that is working under the hood. It is a pretty normal behaviour. If you want to speed up the first call, then you have to work on your backend

Answer (score 1):

try to hit your API on POSTMAN and see the response time.

You can see response time on Postman.

[image]

Note:- Make sure Time shown in Image needs to be Low. If it is taking time is high then you have to sit with your backend people and solve this. This will be nothing with the Retrofit. If it is not then please share your activity code. So we can have a look on it.

Comment: I have hit the API in Postman and readings are same. I will update the question with the code.

Comment: I get the same readings. First API call takes around 1000ms and second one and further API calls take around 300ms. If I wait for 1 minute in Postman and then hit the API, again I get the same behavior.

Comment: You have to work on your first API from backend side and make it smooth. Nothing wrong in retrofit or android. Or may be problem with configuration of your backhend.

Answer (score 0):

I have one option which is not an answer, but can be **workaround** :
If you have splash screen then hit any short API on it from your project because parsing the annotations on the endpoint is done on first use so it takes time for 1st time. Then launch your next screen in the API response(Whatever may be the API response we don't care, just start next screen on it). By doing this your first API will work normally.

> ```
> private void hitAPI() {
> viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
> viewModel.getRepos(SplashScreen.this).observe(SplashScreen.this, new Observer<DashboardModel>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onChanged(DashboardModel response) {
>         if (null!=response && response.isSuccess()) {
>             gotoNextScreen();
>         }
>         else {
>             gotoNextScreen();
>         }
>     }
> }); }
> ```